# A synonym for 'granular' / 'fine-grained'

Tags: single-word-requests

As others have noted for at least a decade, 'granular' has become clichéd in business jargon for 'fine-grained' or just 'precise.'

I'm seeking a word or term (there must be one...) that sounds a little more, well, 'refined' and less trendy, to describe the segmentation of a large group of stuff into smaller and smaller pieces. For example, if a company moved from per-hour billing to per-second billing, I'd like to say they've become more 'fine-grained' -- but I'd like to dodge that grain metaphor.

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: *precise* — which you already mentioned — would work.

Comment: Perhaps *particularized* (or *particularised*) would work in that specific case.

Comment: *We have refined our billing practices.* Surely not possible to find a more refined word (as OP seeks) than *refined* itself?

Comment: FWIW we would talk about granularity in our internal Data Science meetings all the time. I can guarantee you that it was not for want of being trendy, nor would it have made sense to anyone that is only interested in just using business jargon. It has an easily-communicable meaning in technical fields too; don't change from the most appropriate word just because others use it as a buzz-word in abstract business terms

Comment: When you asked your search engine of choice for synonyms, how many did the most copious response throw up?

Comment: *High resolution* is another possibility for the billing, but I'd say is considerably uglier than the alternatives (and not a single word).

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark To me that sounds like they made it more accurate, not that they increased the granularity.

Comment: @Graffito "level of detail" sounds like they added more line items (e.g. different taxes and fees), not increasing the sampling frequency.

Comment: The Company has moved the billing elements to the higher level of **minuteness** to achieve better **exactitude** via more **accurate quantization** of time !