# Word(s) meaning how "high/low resolution", "nested", "shallow/deep" or "derived" ideas/concepts are

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, paired-word-requests

I'm looking for a word or pair of words that refer to whether an idea is "high or low resolution" or high and low levels of analysis. I think a few examples are the best way to convey what I'm hoping to capture:

(1) In your **computer folder**, you may have a folder called "documents" and another folder nested within with the file path like "documents > college > 2023 > spring > intro to chem > lecture 3". So the latter is very nested/derived/high resolution. However, high resolution sounds too value-laiden. (There has been a similar objection in evolution/phylogeny, where people objected to calling some species more "advanced" or "evolved" than others, when the "primitive" condition may in fact be more sophisticated than the evolved version.)

(2) In **chess**, some analyses may be highly nested, or refer to lines of play that involve thinking about several moves in advance. These positions are often called "theoretical" because they are well known, have been played many times, and much strategy or theory is known about them. I want to refer to the "base" vs the highly theoretical or "nested" levels. For example, the King's Indian Defense is defined by: 1. 4, Nf6; 2. c4, g6. Then there is the "Petrosian Variation" which is 7 moves later (7. d5). I want a word that distinguishes between the King's Indian and Petrosian Variation. You might call the King's Indian "high level/low resolution" and the Petrosian "high resolution/low level", but I want a pair of words that are neutral, as "high" makes it sound better when in reality both levels of analysis are important.

(3) In **philosophy**, in an introductory "Philosophy 101" class, you may speak of ideas at a very "high level/low resolution" and speak of the basics--like consequentialism vs intentions, Kant vs Utilitarianism. In contrast, if you're a philosophy academic publishing in journals, you're often writing a response to a response to a response, in a highly "nested" or "derived" manner, as you tend to argue a specific sub-sub-argument (mind-body epiphenomenologist) that are "deeply nested", as opposed to "shallow" broad ideas (Dualist vs Monist).

(4) In **politics**, you may argue about very broad ideas (Safety vs Security; raise lower taxes) or something very specific and abstruse (proposition ABC), which are two different "levels" of political argument.

(5) In **science**, studying cancer, maybe you want a bird's eye/high level view (behaviours leading to cancer/society/health care) or maybe you're interested in the precise, high-resolution molecular events responsible for cancer.

With all of the terms I've used so far--high/low resolution, shallow/deep, high/low level nested, advanced/primitive--there seems to be a negative connotation that I'm not intending. For example, choosing an opening (King's Indian vs Queen's Gambit) can be just as important as very deep theoretical chess lines, despite how broad/shallow the first few moves are. Likewise, addressing the basic questions as an intro philosophy student ("Does God exist?", "Do the ends justify the means?") can be just as important and fruitful as the very abstruse and derived/advanced work academic philosophers do--it would be very dismissive if someone asked "does God exist?" and you respond by saying "that's shallow and low resolution".

So, I'm looking for a word that's generally enough to cover any of these examples, but also neutral and equal in register. The word can be a single word like resolution (ie, low and high resolution) or a pair of words (shallow vs deep). Importantly, I'm hoping for a word that doesn't need explanation or that's immediately discernable regarding what I mean.

Finally, what I currently have in mind is using "high level" vs "high resolution", since to me neither of these sound particularly negative or pejorative to me.

**EDIT on request:**

*Example sentences:*

The chess commentary discussed the Petrosian line, which is much more ______ ["nested, high resolution, etc"] than the general discussion about the Queen's Gambit line. I prefer chess commentary that is at a ______ ["higher level"].

The source of our disagrement about whether free will exists is because my arguments are _____ ["high level"] whereas your objection is a _____ ["high resolution"] concept about modern neuroscience. Let us first return to the _____ ["high level"] point about whether you think free will exists.

Niche philosophical arguments are too dry for my taste. I prefer ____ ["high level, broad, etc"] conversations at dinner parties so everyone feels included.

Comment: Those four examples seem to have almost nothing in common. I'm not sure if there's a single concept that is common to all of them. How are you planning to use this word/phrase?

Comment: Example sentences, please. This is about English Language and Usage -- grammar, in a nutshell -- not vague speculations about "meaning".

Comment: They're all "nested". The computer folders are the most obvious example of nesting. Chess lines are also literally nested. Philosophical arguments are a metaphorical sense of nesting, where similar to chess moves (or folders), you can follow a dichotomous tree or taxonomy and arrive at high or low levels of nesting.

Comment: So what's wrong with *high-level* and *low-level*?  Too *abstract* for you, not *concrete* enough?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark well "low-level" seems too negative and insulting. I wouldn't want to tell someone their idea was "low-level" or "low-resolution" and seem dismissive. Moreover, sometimes "low-resolution" (or whatever the word should be) is a good level of analysis. Sometimes you want a bird's eye view and sometimes the microscopic is the better approach. I'm hoping for something that fits a bit better and/or isn't negative in connotation

Comment: @alphabet in other words, each example is referring to a different **level of analysis**, with some levels being "nested" or supervening on other levels. I'm looking for a natural word to distinguish between a high and a low level of analysis.

Comment: **high level and drilled down analyses** are used in IT and have flowed over to some business contexts: https://www.yellowfinbi.com/glossary/drill-down

Comment: @sat0ri I think that that's still too vague. You need to tell us exactly where/how you plan to use this word/phrase.

Comment: I hear strategic/streamlined, complex/zen, or esoteric/direct. And how are chess lines literally nested? A plan is sequential and strategic.

Comment: general vs. specific

Comment: Or generalist v specialist

Comment: The devil’s in the details, as they say.

Comment: @sat0ri The problem is that those 3 sentences involve completely different concepts; there's nothing in common to give a name to.

Comment: @Lambie high-level and drilled-down analysis is exactly what I had in mind, thank you. Despite being technical, I think those words are relatively self-explanatory. I haven't heard these terms but I could quickly tell this is what I meant.

Comment: @alphabet the three sentences are meant to refer to **granularity**. However, I want something that is neutral, because sometimes the gestalt or big-picture view is just as important as the granular analysis. I could be mistaken, and your criticism is helping me refine and develop what I'm trying to say, but I do think there is a fundamental concept there. Eg, cladistics uses *derived* and *ancestral*, which is the idea that I'm after, without the technical jargon and specialised usage.

Comment: Speaking of psychology terms, top-down and bottom-up are technical terms that refer to this, but are generally relegated to the domain of psychology. Gestaltic vs granular would be good if Gestaltic didn't have such a specific definition.

Comment: This sounds like [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/610420/a-synonym-for-granular-fine-grained).

Comment: How about *specific*?

Answer (score 3):

My answer which aims to satisfy all the examples is

**deep** or **in depth**

1. A computer folder that is found after looking through many sub-folders is at a **deep** level.
2. In chess, a move might be a standard response, or after analysing **in depth**.
3. In philosophy, the opposite of a shallow analysis is **deep**.
4. In politics, an argument can be broad or it can be **in depth**.
5. In science, the analysis might be statistical, or **in depth**.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-depth) has

> **in depth**
> in a serious and detailed way

As for the edited examples:

> The chess commentary discussed the Petrosian line, which is much more **in depth** than the general discussion about the Queen's Gambit line. I prefer chess commentary that is at a **deep** level.

> The source of our disagre**e**ment about whether free will exists is because my arguments are **deep** whereas your objection is a shallow concept about modern neuroscience. Let us first return to the **deeper** point about whether you think free will exists.

> Niche philosophical arguments are too dry for my taste. I prefer ***general*** conversations at dinner parties so everyone feels included.

The last example is an exception, which I can't fit into the idea of the question. It's a dinner party.

Note that I reversed the sense of **high** to **deep**. IMO saying 'high' has an implicit value judgement that this mode is somehow *better* than other modes of analysis.

Comment: Deep is great, and agree "high" has an implicit value judgement. I certainly don't want to have a negative value judgement, which might come as insulting in a conversation, so at least "high" is flattering; but I agree it's not ideal. If I could find a converse to deep/depth it would be perfect. "General" does work, but it's missing the *zhuzh* I'm after

Comment: I don't see how the dinner party example is relevant to the context of the question. You could say "I prefer **more stimulating** conversation at dinner parties" but it still doesn't quite marry with "so everyone feels included".

Comment: I'm looking for a pair of words, depth vs breadth, big picture vs granular. At a dinner party, whether you like bigger picture topics (maybe because they're more far-reaching and impactful) or more granular topics (maybe because you're an expert and you have very considered opinions and are sick of the "high-level" introductory questions), I'm just looking for a word/set of words that span across the continuum of granularity/level of analysis/lucidity/zoomed in or out. Am I being any clearer?

Comment: The question wasn't so clear: it seemed to ask for one half of that. Would **dichotomy** work? Or do you want  a word pair that will apply to every situation you can imagine – from disk file storage to dinner parties?

Answer (score 1):

### One word cannot fit all; don’t force it to

One pair of words won’t fit all situations. The examples you give are not really comparable - some compare abstract concepts; others, concrete things, so no single word-pair will fit all of them. Resist the urge to find The One Universal Adjective - language doesn’t work like that. (Well, interesting and engaging language doesn’t work like that).

Choose one from the left column, one from the right.  I’ve tried to put the antonyms on the same row, but for words that don’t have a common antonym, I haven’t tried to force one.

#### Adjectives

| Low detail, big scope | High detail, small scope |
| --- | --- |
| General | Specific, Special |
| Broad | Narrow |
| Superficial | Deep |
| Over-arching |  |
| Accessible |  |
|  | Esoteric |
| High-level | Low-level |
| First approximation |  |
| Global | Local |
| Universal |  |
|  | Particular |
| Zoomed-out | Zoomed-in |
| Root |  |

#### Nouns

Use these as “the [insert word] of ~ ”.

| Low detail, big scope | High detail, small scope |
| --- | --- |
| fundamentals | minutiae |
| essentials | technicalities |
| principles |  |
| essence |  |
| broad outlines | fine details |